# Find correspondence between two sets of 2D points

Tags: points, feature-extraction, stereo-3d, feature-descriptor, correspondence

I have two sets of 2D Points (shown in images below).
And I would like to find some high confidence correspondence between these dots.

These dots are extracted feature points from 2 camera images from different angles. Two images are relatively well rectified, though not perfect. However, there will be distortion/warp caused by depth in the scene, the number of points might not be the same, there might be outliers, etc.

[image: Left View]
[image: Right View]

One approach could be using a sliding window that contains multiple dots and try block matching. But that might be kind of slow. I feel like there should be a relatively straight forward solution to this problem.

For example, [this paper](http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1362&context=robotics) might be addressing a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use each dot/point in one of the images, and search for its "neighbors" in the other image.

Just a few days ago someone asked a similar question here, and got a very sophisticated (accepted) answer:

[How to calculate the nearest neighbors using weka from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31350506/how-to-calculate-the-nearest-neighbors-using-weka-from-the-command-line)

But maybe your problem is so common in image processing that there are even better solutions, but you might try this one (implemented in java).